# Kafka latency optimization

Tags: apache-kafka

My kafka version is 0.10.2.1.
My service have really low qps (1msg/sec). And our requirement for rtt is really strict. ( 99.9% < 30ms)
Currently I've encounter a problem, when kafka run for a long time, 15 days or so, performance start to go down.
2017-10-21 was like

```
Time .                num of msgs .  percentage
cost<=2ms             0             0.000%

2ms<cost<=5ms         12391         32.659%

5ms<cost<=8ms         25327         66.754%

8ms<cost<=10ms        186           0.490%

10ms<cost<=15ms       24            0.063%

15ms<cost<=20ms       2             0.005%

20ms<cost<=30ms       0             0.000%

30ms<cost<=50ms       4             0.011%

50ms<cost<=100ms      1             0.003%

100ms<cost<=200ms     0             0.000%

200ms< cost<=300ms    6             0.016%

300ms<cost<=500ms     0             0.000%

500ms<cost<=1s        0             0.000%

cost>1s               0             0.000%
```

But recently, it became :

```
cost<=2ms            0              0.000%

2ms<cost<=5ms        7592           29.202%

5ms<cost<=8ms        17470          67.197%

8ms<cost<=10ms       698            2.685%

10ms<cost<=15ms      143            0.550%

15ms<cost<=20ms      23             0.088%

20ms<cost<=30ms      19             0.073%

30ms<cost<=50ms      11             0.042%

50ms<cost<=100ms     5              0.019%

100ms<cost<=200ms    11            0.042%

200m s<cost<=300ms   26             0.100%

300ms<cost<=500ms    0              0.000%

500ms<cost<=1s       0             0.000%

cost>1s              0              0.000%
```

When I check the log, I don't see a way to check the reason why a specific message have a high rtt. And if there's any way to optimize(OS tune, broker config), please enlighten me

Comment: Could you share your broker an client configurations? After restarting the clients does the performance improve?

Comment: num.network.threads=3 num.io.threads=10 message.max.bytes=10000120 replica.fetch.max.bytes=10000120 min.insync.replicas = 2 connections.max.idle.ms = 86400000 leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=30 log.dirs=/home/disk0/kafka,/home/disk1/kafka,/home/disk2/kaf‌​ka,/home/disk3/kafka‌​,/home/ssd1/kafka,/h‌​ome/ssd2/kafka num.partitions = 20 num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 2 num.replica.fetchers = 3 default.replication.factor = 3 unclean.leader.election.enable = false

Comment: Except for that, on the client side, required.acks will always set to -1, and My 3 brokers are in 3 different data center but  in one city, average ping between each two of them is about 1.5ms

Comment: Are you monitoring any system/app statistics?

Comment: cpu idle is 98% ~ 99% on average, memory got 85% percent free( 128g total) qps is pretty low so network IO is low. Also  I've set vm.swappiness = 0 to disable swap. But I haven't put jmx on monitor yet.

Comment: I think you're going to need to setup JMX monitoring or else your just going to have blindly tune a bunch of different things. I'd look at things like the response time between the producer to the broker and the broker to the consumer first. After that you'll know generally where to look first

Answer (score 2):

Without the request handling time break-down it is hard to tell which part maybe the culprit of your issue. More specifically you'll need to hook up your jmx and check the following request-level metrics:

TotalTimeMs
RequestQueueTimeMs
LocalTimeMs
RemoteTimeMs
ResponseQueueTimeMs
ResponseSendTimeMs

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring

Check their avg / 99 percentile value over time and see which one is contributing to the perf degradation.

Comment: fetchFollowerTotalMs 99th and avg both very high... cpu idle always above 94%. mem used 15% , disk io utils below 5%, what went wrong..

Comment: So what does remoteTimeMs and localTimeMs mean in fetchFollower, not sure which is remote which is local

Comment: If most of the latency comes form fetch follower, then it may indicate your follower fetcher thread is too busy fetching from leaders. For fetch follower there should be no remote time, and local time includes the time spent on appending fetched records to local log.

Comment: Given that our cpu and network usage are both low, should I increase fetch thread numbers? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider upgrading to 0.11 (or 1.00) which has performance improvements in it
2. Optimisation article: https://www.confluent.io/blog/optimizing-apache-kafka-deployment/